# Have the indispensability arguments been examined for probability theory?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, probability

Indispensability arguments are widely known in the philosophy of mathematics, the idea being (roughly) that we should commit to the existence of those mathematical entities that are indispensable for science. There is a huge literature here, covering many different examples and with many different interpretations on how we might cash out "indispensable". Let's bracket those details.

My question concerns whether people have examined the indispensability arguments with respect to *probability* theory (and generalisations thereof, like the use of amplitudes in quantum mechanics). Is there work on this?

Comment: An interesting question. Probability is very different from more traditional mathematics in physics in the sense that it can't be seen as expressing the intuitive idea of a law of nature unless you posit odd special entities such as propensities. So if it could be shown that probability is indispensable in the same sense as, for example, numbers, that would act as a counter-argument to indispensability arguments for people who reject things like propensities.

Comment: @NeilBarton I learn from https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathphil-indis/#WhatItIndi „What we require for an entity to be ‘dispensable’ is for it to be eliminable and that the theory resulting from the entity’s elimination be an attractive theory. (Perhaps, even stronger, we require that the resulting theory be more attractive than the original.)“ – For me it looks funny when philosophers reason what is indispensible and what is dispensible in mathematics: People who live in glass houses shouldn’t throw stones.:-)

Comment: @DavidGudeman This is a fair point. Robert Black also suggested an explanation along these lines---roughly that the relationship between credence and chance (and probability) was not sufficiently well understood to say anything one way or another. I am rather struck by the (possibly naive) thought that, as things stand, amplitudes are clearly indispensable for our best scientific theories, so something like probabilities are indispensable for our best scientific theories.